# how do i pass a variable from PHP to my html text ,so that it changes depending on the value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am no very experienced with PHP, so excuse any errors that may be present.I am trying to return the values retrieved from the SQL table.

this is my search.php file

```
include 'dbh.php';
$GENRE=$_GET['genre'];
$BOOKNAME=$_GET['bookname'];
$OFFER=$_GET['offertype'];
$PUB=$_GET['publisher'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%' AND GENRE LIKE '$GENRE' AND PUBLISHER LIKE '$PUB%'  ";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "   "."<br>";
    echo $row['BOOKNAME'] ."<br>";
    echo $row['GENRE'] ."<br>";
    echo $row['AUTHOR'] ."<br>";
    echo $row['PUBLISHER'] ."<br>"; 
}
```

this is my searchpage.html file. I am trying to change the text within the  tag with the book1 id.

```
form id="browse" action="search.php" method="GET"  >
                <fieldset>
                    <select name="genre">
                        <option value="Genre" selected>Genre</option>
                        <option value="fantasy">fantasy</option>
                        <option value="Non-fiction">Non-fiction</option>
                        <option value="Science fiction">Science fiction</option>
                        <option value="Satire">Satire</option>
                        <option value="drama">Drama</option>
                        <option value="Action &#38;"> Action and Adventure</option>
                        <option value="romance">Romance</option>
                        <option value="mystery">Mystery</option>
                        <option value="horror">Horror</option>
                        <option value="health">Health</option>
                        <option value="travel">Travel</option>

                    </select>
                    <input type="search" name ="bookname"placeholder="Browse Books">
                    <input  type="submit"  value="Search" > 



                </fieldset>

        </header> <!-- End of main header tag -->





           <div class="filt" >
              <ul >

                  <li onclick="myFunction()" >Offer type</li>
                  <li id="myDIV">
                       <ul>
                          <li><input type="radio" checked="checked"  name="offertype">all</input></li>
                          <li><input type="radio" value="free" name="offertype">free</input></li>
                          <li><input type="radio" value="trade"name="offertype">trade</input></li>
                          <li><input type="radio" value="sell" name="offertype">sell</input></li>
                        </ul>
                  </li>

              </ul> 
             </div>

         <div class="result" >
            <ul>
                  <li><a href="#home" id="book1">  </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Book2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Book3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">Book4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">Book5</a></li>
            </ul>

         </div>
         </form>
```

Comment: It sounds like you simply want to `echo` the variable. When the variable changes, what is echoed will automatically update.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Here you have to use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML - you can find more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)). It is a basic way to have communication in PHP and HTML file. By using JavaScript you can send data to the PHP file and then Javascript will receive the values printed by echo in PHP (in the form of string), which is then can be assigned to that "book1" id.

So resultant code will be:
Search.php:

```html
include 'dbh.php';
$GENRE=$_GET['genre'];
$BOOKNAME=$_GET['bookname'];
$OFFER=$_GET['offertype'];
$PUB=$_GET['publisher'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%' AND GENRE LIKE '$GENRE' AND PUBLISHER LIKE '$PUB%'  ";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['BOOKNAME']; 
}
```

searchpage.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>

<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 

<script>
function Search()
{
 var _genre, _bookName, _offerType, _url;
    var doc = document.getElementsByName("genre")[0];
    _genre = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value;
    
    _bookName = document.getElementsByName("bookname")[0].value;
    _offerType =document.getElementsByName("offertype")[0].value;
    _url = "Search.php?genre=" + _genre + "&bookname=" + _bookName + "&offertype=" + _offerType ;
    
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("book1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", _url, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
<form id="browse" action="search.php" method="GET"  >
    <fieldset>
      <select name="genre">
        <option value="Genre" selected>Genre</option>
        <option value="fantasy">fantasy</option>
        <option value="Non-fiction">Non-fiction</option>
        <option value="Science fiction">Science fiction</option>
        <option value="Satire">Satire</option>
        <option value="drama">Drama</option>
        <option value="Action &#38;"> Action and Adventure</option>
        <option value="romance">Romance</option>
        <option value="mystery">Mystery</option>
        <option value="horror">Horror</option>
        <option value="health">Health</option>
        <option value="travel">Travel</option>
      </select>
      <input type="search" name ="bookname"placeholder="Browse Books">
      <input  type="button"  value="Search" onClick = "Search()"> 
    </fieldset>
    <div class="filt" >
      <ul >
        <li onclick="myFunction()" >Offer type</li>
        <li id="myDIV">
          <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" checked="checked"  name="offertype">all</li>
            <li><input type="radio" value="free" name="offertype">free</li>
            <li><input type="radio" value="trade"name="offertype">trade</li>
            <li><input type="radio" value="sell" name="offertype">sell</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul> 
    </div>

    <div class="result" >
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" id="book1">  </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Book3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Book4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Book5</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code shows these variables in html. And if you change them in sql database, then the html will also change.

But your search.php will appear as white site so before you type php, you can put some html to give it better look. But if you would like to change something depending on search result for example for book "xyz" make some special container, you can make it using if statement.

I hope, I answered your question, if not please let me know and give some more details about the problem.

EDIT:
the piece of code that you could use:

searchpage.php

```
<html>
    Some html 
    <?php 
        require_once("search.php");
        printResult();
    ?>
</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php
function printResult(){
    include 'dbh.php';
    $GENRE=$_GET['genre'];
    $BOOKNAME=$_GET['bookname'];
    $OFFER=$_GET['offertype'];
    $PUB=$_GET['publisher'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
    BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%' AND GENRE LIKE '$GENRE' AND PUBLISHER LIKE '$PUB%'  ";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "   "."<br>";
        echo $row['BOOKNAME'] ."<br>";
        echo $row['GENRE'] ."<br>";
        echo $row['AUTHOR'] ."<br>";
        echo $row['PUBLISHER'] ."<br>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it appears the version I uploaded is missing the header that returns you to searchpage.html. what I'm trying to accomplish is change the text within a HTML tag so that it prints the SQL query results between the tags

Comment: So you should put all code of search.php into function for example printResult() and then type require_once("search.php") (It will include this file) in result page and call it using printResult(). It will print results in this place where you've put code to call function. But i suggest to change that page to .php, because some servers may have trouble with proccessing it. If you have still some trouble, please let me know, so I'll write this piece of code for you.

Answer (score 0):

No time to check the whole thing properly but set a variable in php somewhere above the "book1" result which variable will contain what comes from your database.

```
$variable = 'whatever you decide this value to be'; //or in your case whatever comes from the database
```

down where the html is displayed with the mentioned "book1" change it to this

```
<li><a href="#home" id="book1"> <?php echo '$variable'; ?> </a></li>
```